# Android: How to handle when Realm finishes sync?

Tags: android, realm

I want to start (on background) sync with Realm Object Server when launching my Android app. And after data was successfully downloaded I want to show toast.

How I can do this?  What method do I need to use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried this but it should work.

```
private void setRealmDefaultConfiguration(SyncUser syncUser, String realmURL) {
    SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, realmURL)
            .waitForInitialRemoteData()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}

public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private static boolean firstInit = true;

    protected Realm realm = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        final boolean shouldShowToast;
        if(firstInit) {
            firstInit = false;
            shouldShowToast = true;
        } else {
            shouldShowToast = false;
        }
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        Realm.getInstanceAsync(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration(), new Realm.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Realm realm) {
                if(isChangingConfigurations() || isFinishing()) {
                    realm.close();
                } else {
                    BaseActivity.this.realm = realm;
                    onRealmLoaded(realm);
                }
                if(shouldShowToast) {
                    Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, R.string.data.loaded, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                // boop
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onRealmLoaded(Realm realm) {
        // override this if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing I'm not sure about is rotations. But I also don't really wanna cancel the `Realm.getInstanceAsync()` call. Maybe it should be in a retained fragment or ViewModel or something.